# AngularJS doesn't apply CSS the same way as regular HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have the following regular html which renders correctly:

```
<div class="media-left">
                      <div class="user-wrapper">
                        <img src="myimage.jpg"  class="img-circle" width="80">
                        <div><a href="#">Some entry</a></div>
                        <div class="date">Now</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

I then have another snippet that is rendered in an angular for loop using a controller:

```
<div class="media-left">
                      <div class="user-wrapper">
                        <img ng-src="myimage.jpg"  class="img-circle" width="80" src="myimage.jpg">
                        <div><a href="#" class="ng-binding">some entry</a></div>
                        <div class="date"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Here is my css:

```
ul.timeline-list > li.media > .media-left {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
ul.timeline-list > li.media > .media-left .user-wrapper {
  width: 120px;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  ul.timeline-list > li.media > .media-left {
    margin-left: -20px;
  }
  ul.timeline-list > li.media > .media-left img {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  ul.timeline-list > li.media > .media-left {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
  }
}
ul.timeline-list > li.media > .media-left a {
  background: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  padding: 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.timeline-list > li.media > .media-left .date {
  background: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  color: #bdbdbd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.timeline-list > li.media > .media-left .user-wrapper {
  width: 120px;
}
```

when i remove the "media-left" class from the working entry, it looks exactly like the distorted image.

Here is what it looks like with the top working and bottom misaligned:

[image]

I followed @E.King advice below and added:

```
.container {
  font-size: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  word-spacing: 0px;
}

.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1em;
  word-spacing: 2em;
}

<div class="media-left container">
```

And the format is much closer with the icon now aligned center, but how can I make the icon go above the grey bar?:

[image]

What am I doing wrong that the second entry has a distorted format?

Comment: Does the class `ng-binding` have any CSS that would throw off the formatting? Is your `date` div possibly not rendering correctly because it is empty in the second example? It's tough to know without any idea what exactly "distorted" means.

Comment: Provide the CSS and maybe we could tell you.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I added the css.  when i remove the "media-left" class from the working entry, it looks exactly like the distorted image.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `width="80"` instead of `style="width: 80px;"` ?  I wouldn't recommend inline style anyway, but the second option is better if you choose to do them.  Not sure if this will fix your issue but it stuck out to me.

Comment: @Santi I do not have any ng-binding conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding !important to the .media-left margin-left? Maybe some further CSS is getting applied after the initial render and overriding the margin behavior you set.

It could also be a problem with whitespace, as per: [Angularjs List Item Margin Issue Combining ng-repeat elements with static ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092045/angularjs-list-item-margin-issue-combining-ng-repeat-elements-with-static-ones)

As per other issues with ng-repeat, it looks like your CSS class simply isn't being applied after the element is rendered. This is somewhat common with positioning in ng-repeat. You could try using ng-class or ng-style directly to set the correct margin and z-index as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31346226/6452040).

Comment: Add `important`? No. Just no.

Comment: @Yatrix haha, when all you have is a hammer.

Comment: @Atma "I just have this bazooka laying around and I need to drill a hole in the wall, so..."